# Template is not rerendering / auto-updating loop about changed controller variable

Tags: ember.js

Given 2 array items when I add new input then I want to see 3 array items but still only see 2 array items.

This is my current code ...

**Route**

```
    model: (params) ->
      @controllerFor('pages').set 'myArray', []
```

**Template**

```
<ul>
  {{#each myArray as |item itemIndex|}}
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
<input id="my_input"/><button {{action 'addInput'}}/>
```

**Controller**

```
    addInput: ->
      array = @get('myArray')
      array.push $('#my_input').val()
      @set 'myArray', array
```

How can I get the template to rerender / auto-update the loop about changed controller variable "myArray"?

I'm using Ember 1.13.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` is native JavaScript Array function. To make your templates rerender, the change of the data must be propagated and notify the template to rerender. Because of that, Ember API provides polyfills for native Arrays objects or, if you cannot use polyfills, gives you an `Ember.A` class that wraps the native Array.

Simply, just use [`#pushObject`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_pushObject) method instead of `push`. [Take a look here to see more of KVO (key-value observing) compliant methods](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html).